# Batch Log Off Countdown

Tags: batch-file, cmd, logoff

I am trying to create a batch file that will countdown when activated and logoff of the system. This is for when the user is no longer at the computer. I have come across multiple forums where people are doing this but they log off any time the user is idle for x minutes or seconds. What I have does count down and does log off or cancel and I have it set in the task scheduler to start when the computer has been idle. That part is working fine. What I cannot seem to get to work right is to only perform the countdown if the time is after 6:30 PM (18:30). It has worked once for me but I cannot get it to work anymore.

So what I need in a more specific sequence.

- Needs to check the time to make sure it is after 6:30 pm
- Needs to exit if time is not yet 6:30 pm without user interaction.
- begin log off sequence if time is after 6:30 pm

The stuff below seems to be working perfectly as of right now.

- press any letter key to cancel the sequence
- force log off if the sequence is not canceled

Here is my code right now which works, it just doesn't care about what time it is.

```
TITLE Automatic Log Off Initiated!

mode con:cols=80 lines=1

COLOR CF

@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set tm=%time%
:: Test data on lines below.
:: set tm=18:59:59.00
:: set tm=19:00:00.00
:: set tm=19:44:59.00
:: set tm=19:45:00.00
:: set tm=23:59:59.99
set hh=!tm:~0,2!
set mm=!tm:~3,2!
if !hh! LEQ 18 if !mm! LEQ 30 (
    exit
)
else goto :begin

:begin
for /l %%N in (600 -1 1) do (
  set /a "min=%%N/60, sec=%%N%%60, n-=1"
  if !sec! lss 10 set sec=0!sec!
  cls
  choice /c:1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ /n /m "Automatically Logging Off in !min!:!sec! - Press any key or move the mouse to cancel" /t 1 /d 1
  if not errorlevel 1 goto :break
  if errorlevel 2 goto :end
  if errorlevel 3 goto :end
  if errorlevel 4 goto :end
  if errorlevel 5 goto :end
  if errorlevel 6 goto :end
  if errorlevel 7 goto :end
  if errorlevel 8 goto :end
  if errorlevel 9 goto :end
  if errorlevel 10 goto :end
  if errorlevel 11 goto :end
  if errorlevel 12 goto :end
  if errorlevel 13 goto :end
  if errorlevel 14 goto :end
  if errorlevel 15 goto :end
  if errorlevel 16 goto :end
  if errorlevel 17 goto :end
  if errorlevel 18 goto :end
  if errorlevel 19 goto :end
  if errorlevel 20 goto :end
  if errorlevel 21 goto :end
  if errorlevel 22 goto :end
  if errorlevel 23 goto :end
  if errorlevel 24 goto :end
  if errorlevel 25 goto :end
  if errorlevel 26 goto :end
  if errorlevel 27 goto :end
)




:break
shutdown /l /f

:end
exit
```

I have played with it to test the time using different times but it still does not work.

I have also tried using a second IF statement but that did not work.

```
IF !hh! GTR 18 IF !mm! GTR 30 (
goto :begin
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
set hh=!tm:~0,2!
set mm=!tm:~3,2!
if !hh! LEQ 18 if !mm! LEQ 30 (
    exit
)
else goto :begin
```

Incorrect syntax. The "else" keyword **must** be on the same line as the close-parenthesis for the `if-true` action statement.

What is happening is that this `else` clause will produce an error message, but batch then proceeds to the `:begin` label anyway and the message is cleared from the screen by the `cls` within the `for` loop.

The `!var!` syntax is unnecessary in this part of the code. It is only required within a code block (ie. parenthesised series of statements.)

Be careful. `hh` or `mm` may be set with a leading "0", which batch regards as **octal** hence `08` and `09` are invalid.

In this case, batch will recognise that it can't concert `08` or `09` so it switches to normal (string-comparison) mode and correctly compares the **strings** to `18` and `30`.

But here's a trap. If you were to replace `30` with `7` then you'd find that `08` and `09` were **less** than `7`. This is because when you "switch" to `string-comparison` mode (actually you **don't** switch to numeric-comparison mode because one side or the other can't be converted to an integer) the comparison is performed character-by-character from the left, and `"0"` is less than `"7"`

It only appears to work because of the particular number you've chosen don't fall foul of this mechanism. I call it a fail-to-fail scenario. It's quite common - because it hasn't been observed to fail, it's assumed to be working, until one day someone changes something and it breaks...

Next problem is a misunderstanding of `if errorlevel`.

`IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0. So is `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0`, except that the former can be used within a block but the latter cannot.

Your code is set up to individually test the other errorlevels. If you were to change the code to

```
if errorlevel 2 echo TWO&goto :end
if errorlevel 3 echo THREE&goto :end
```

(look - to save time, don't bother with the reminder)

and insert a `pause` before your `exit`

```
:end
pause
exit
```

then you'd see the message produced. Press an alphabetic key, and the report will be `TWO` because `if errorlevel 2 echo TWO&goto :end` will echo `TWO` and go to `:end` if `errorlevel` is set to 2 **or to greater than 2**

If you are really using `choice` to make a menu, then the correct procedure is to test in **reverse-numerical** order. It's redundant here because with your code, pressing `X` (for instance) will set `errorlevel` to 25 and 25>2, so the test for `errorlevel` 2 will exit the procedure and close the window.

Again, a fail-to-fail scenario.

Comment: This definitely shines a light on some things and it makes more sense to me now thank you for your input I am still working out some kinks (it has logged me off and it is before 6:30pm) but I replaced the `else` with `if hh GTR 18 if mm GTR 30` and hopefully that will help. is there a better way to do any of this? I am always open to improvement.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling a little more I noticed in another file (copy) that I had

```
:begin
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for...
```

as I looked closely at the two files I noticed the capital letters at the start of the second and third words. I changed this for the code at the top where it says `setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` and I changed the first letters to be capital `setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion` which fixed everything and now it cancels and exits if the time is not yet 6:30 pm and if its after 6:30 then it begins the shutdown sequence and it is working beautifully! so thank you for any of your thoughts but I answered it myself! :D

Hopefully this may be helpful to someone else in the future as well!

Comment: Um, no - sorry. Batch keywords are largely case-insensitive - the only place it recognises case is in the instance of *metavariables* (loop-control variables).